# How to present changes to public after using git?

Tags: git, version-control

I'm a newbie in git. After I finish messing with the versions and stuff, how can I deploy my final version to the /var/www/html directory? I cloned the repo, but there is probably a better way of doing it. Thanks!

I'd like to update /var/www/html (i.e what the end user sees) whenever I push updates to /user/my-repo.git

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I have git repo on my remote server /user/my-repo.git. I'd like to update /var/www/html (i.e what the end user sees) whenever I push updates to /user/my-repo.git

Comment: have you tried some git hooks? you might find this instructive http://danbarber.me/using-git-for-deployment/

Comment: @talhof9: You just put another git clone in /var/www/html. Then you can follow the exact instructions in the other question.

Comment: OK, I set up the .git in the /var/www/html directory. How can I protect it from being accessed from browser? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Here's an alternative method that seems quite good to me, and avoids the `.git` directory issue http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto .  There is some information here about how to make the `.git` directory inaccessible from the web: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142437/make-git-directory-web-inaccessible

Comment: It works finally, thank you very much! I combined your solutions

Comment: @talhof9: Glad you found a solution. If you can explain your solution in detail, please provide it as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of git is to do *version control*, to deploy you could use `git archive` to make a tarball/zip file. Or copy the relevant files directly.