# Make the deny from all for .git directory more user friendly

Tags: git, security, .htaccess

RE: [Make .git directory web inaccessible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142437/make-git-directory-web-inaccessible)

I currently have the following:

```
<Directorymatch "^/.*/\.git/">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directorymatch>
```

Instead of a 500 error page, is there a way to modify the .htaccess code above to make it just go to the main domain? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

I also have the following mod_rewrite which got me closer:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule "^(.*/)?\.git/" http://%{HTTP_HOST}/? [L]
```

However, it only triggers if its "domain.com/.git" and not any child .git folders. E.g.

```
domain.com/folder/.git
domain.com/folder/sub-folder/.git
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Alright, this seems to work for what I was asking.

**Solution 1**. If you would like to redirect to the domain root (w/ mod_rewrite):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?\.git+ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/? [L]
```

**Solution 2**. If you would like to issue a 404 (w/ mod_rewrite):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?\.git+ - [R=404,L]
```

**Fallback solution**. if mod_rewrite ain't available:

```
RedirectMatch 404 ^(.*/)?\.git+
```

I went with Solution 2, and the fallback. I hope that helps.