# Drupal Site with Existing Data, properly setting up Git Repo on server to push local code

Tags: git, drupal, drupal-7

I had some issues pushing updates via FTPloy, so I decided to set up Git on the client's dedicated host. Installation went beautifully. I created a --bare repo in the /public_html directory where the Drupal files are stored. I set up this repo as a remote, and attempted to push new updates to it. Unfortunately, this did not work. It appears as if everything was sent just fine, but this is not the case. I check the site, and no changes are apparent.

Could this be an issue with my configuration, or am I missing some steps in the process to set up a repo and have it recognize the local changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the `--bare` option, the repository you created just handles the history but no actual source code. Your pushes update this history, but the changes will never be reflected on the source files: git isn't even aware of them, it only uses the `.git` folder.

Bare repositories are used to share changes to the source code, see [this article](http://www.saintsjd.com/2011/01/what-is-a-bare-git-repository/) for more information.

To deploy your site with git, just delete the .git folder which was created and drop the --bare option when re-creating the repository. You may want to do a local backup first.

One last tip : this .git folder git uses internally should not be accessible from the Web, you might have to prevent this. Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142437/make-git-directory-web-inaccessible) for solutions.

Comment: Worked beautifully ThibWeb. Thanks so much for the assistance.