# Hide .git directory or file with apache

Tags: git, apache

I want to deny the access to `.git` directory (I personally changed the `.git` folder location so it created a `.git` file that has a path to the `.git` folder).

I am using Apache 2.4.18. This is what I added to the apache2.conf at the bottom of the file

```
# Include my personal config
Include personal.conf
```

And inside `personal.conf` I wrote:

```
<DirectoryMatch "^\.git">
    Require all denied
</DirectoryMatch>

<FilesMatch "^\.git">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
```

So, this will deny access to that file/directory starting with `.git` in any location that the user via URL can.
Am I right? I mean by this, if a user try to access **`www.example.com/.git`*** or **`www.example.com/---/---/---/---/---/.gitsomething`**

Will this work for any virtualhost ? Any recommendations ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The actual `Directorymatch` expression should be:

```
<Directorymatch "^/.*/\.git/">
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
</Directorymatch>
```

But this is not the standard best practice:

```
RedirectMatch 404 /\.git
```

Not only this deny `.git` access, but the user is not even aware of the existence of a git repo.

Comment: Yes, I saw that was giving a Forbidden showing that file exists. Two questions, the first one about directorymatch, the expression start with /.*/ to tell that ANY FOLDER, right ? And the second, the redirectmatch should go in the conf I wrote ? thanks !

Comment: @P0lT10n Actually, if it is OK with you, I will close it as duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/6142437/6309. Yes to your first question, and "in an .htaccess file at the root of your web server"

Comment: It is not an exact duplicate because I want to use apache conf, not .htacess, because I am testing this in my own ubuntu server for development, not production, so it is easier for me to write it in an apache conf and automatically apply it to all posible virtualhosts, but if you want, close it as duplicated. Thanks

Comment: @P0lT10n yes, the RedirectMatch is easier, best practice, and should be valid for all VirtualHost.

Comment: Have I to write it in a single line in my `personal.conf` as you wrote it, right ? I know how to use it in .htaccess but not in apache configuration.

Comment: @P0lT10n if your personnal config is included in the main apache2.conf one, that should work just fine. To be tested though.

Comment: RedirectMatch 404 /\.git  Working in global (personal) server .conf. Tested on Apache 2.4.6