# Requests to .htaccess should return 404 instead of 403

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-403

This is sort of a follow-up to [*Is there a way to force apache to return 404 instead of 403?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1486304/367456) which suggested `RedirectMatch` to 404 to accomplish this.

It works perfectly fine for most of anything, however if I request:

```
 http://example.com/.htaccess
```

I get a 403 and not a 404 if I have (or not) this in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RedirectMatch 404 ^/\.htaccess$
```

Is there a way to override the default 403 - Forbidden behavior of apache from inside the `.htaccess` file itself?

Comment: This has to be done on the main Apache configuration file or in your vhost, where access to .ht* files are returned with HTTP 403. You can simply change it there without having to do rewrite.

Comment: @thephpdeveloper: add that as an answer instead of a comment :)

Comment: Thanks guys for confirming this. I only saw this one particular line once on the `httpd.conf` file relating to the `.ht*` files handling, so daren't confirm this.

Comment: @thephpdeveloper: No it has [*not*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7945795/requests-to-htaccess-should-return-404-instead-of-403/7945851#7945851) to be done in the main apache config file or vhost configuration.

Comment: And for the close-voters: I need this for the URL layout of my application configuration, I don't want to re-configure the whole server which I can not anyway as it's shared hosting (a fine one with git if that matters). So I would merely think of it as any other mod_rewrite configuration question here on SO which are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just after I posted my question, I came to a solution towards the following:

- Mimic the default server configuration's `<Files>` rules for `.ht` type of files.
- Allow them.
- Redirect them to 404.

Works like this:

```
<Files ~ "^\.ht">
  Order Deny,Allow
  Allow from all
  Satisfy All
  Redirect 404 /
</Files>
```