# Why can i download a file that it secured with htaccess file ?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, xampp

This is the htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 400 /index.php
   ErrorDocument 401 /index.php
   ErrorDocument 403 /index.php
   ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
   ErrorDocument 405 /index.php

   <Files configure.php>
      order allow,deny
      deny from all
   </Files>
```

the file configure.php is in some folder lets say /config/configure.php
and now the problem is that I can download it ! by just making a link to it.
And it is because of this line ErrorDocument 404 /index.php, when I delete this line I
get a 404 error and cannot download the configure.php file. But why is it like so that
this line (that I want to have) makes it possible to download the configure.php file ?

Comment: your fine shroud be `.htaccess` not `htaccess` .... Tested it locally and it works fine ...

Answer (score 2):

You need to place the `.htaccess` file (*not* `htaccess` without the leading dot) into the folder where `configure.php` resides in (at least) to make the [`<Files configure.php>`-directive<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#files) work. See as well [Filesystem, Webspace, and Boolean Expressions<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/sections.html#file-and-web).

Related: [Requests to .htaccess should return 404 instead of 403](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7945795/367456)