# mod rewrite all url's except includes (js/css/img/some php)

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

What I want is a Wordpress type of URL rewrite.

What I have now is:

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ rewrite.php?data=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This almost works rewriting everything except existing files (css,js etc files are not rewritten as expected).

The problems I have with this are:

1. `.css`, `.js`, Image and PHP files are also accessible by entering their file name. eg.: `domain.com/style.css` will be accessible by anyone.
2. I want some existing files(only php right now) to be redirected anyway. eg.: domain.com/movies.php should redirect to rewrite.php(include 404.php) and domain.com/movies or domain.com/movies/ would include movies.php page.

Ideally I would also be able to change user entered URL from `domain.com/movies` to `domain.com/movies/` for consistency more than anything else.

I want to keep `.htaccess` to a bare minimum. Does wordpress rewrite everything including `.css` files?

What I want:

1. Some php files to redirect others not. eg: includes/func.inc.php
   should not be accessible to the users, while movies.php should be
   accessible but ONLY from this url domain.com/movies/

(not essential)

1. Change url to canonical url eg: domain.com/movies to
   domain.com/movies/ (some resources on how to achieve this would be
   nice). Note: domain.com/movies url should still work but appear with
   a slash at the end either via rewrite or maybe by just adding a
   slash    with javasript (faster?)
2. Make .css/.js files inaccessible by the user. eg: domain.com/style.css should redirect the user to a 404 page

Comment: The rule you have now shouldn't rewrite urls for your css/javascript files since you have a `! -f` in your RewriteCond.  Are you finding that it does anyways?

Comment: No, it doesn't, what I want is to make these files inaccessible via url (not essential) and have some php files/page redirected but not inlude files or few other php files.

Comment: @EricPetroelje: While working on the formatting of the question I asked myself exactly the same. Also: You could check that things are not a directory and link as well (the later is missed by Wordpress IIRC) *and* the slash at the end is called canonical URLs / directories, you can read about that in the Apache documentation, there are different ways / settings / directives to deal with that, so this must not be done within the rewrite module.

Comment: @DominicM: Your comment does not make it any clearer for me. Can you please elaborate what you want with the `.css` files to happen? And when you write *redirect* what do you mean? A URL-Rewrite or the technical HTTP redirect that is communicating with the browser telling where to go instead?

Comment: Ok, what I want to happen to css/js and php includes is to redirect them to 404 page when accessed by the user(this is not essential). As for movies.php I want it accessible only by domain.com/movies/. By redirect I mean URL-Rewrite.

Comment: @hakre I omitted directory check as I do not want users to be able to access /browse files on the server. What do you mean by link? do you just mean absolute links(not external server). If so that may actually work if I change all site url's to absolute url's but I don't know if that's possible work...

Comment: I read 404, maybe this QA material is of use to you: [Requests to .htaccess should return 404 instead of 403](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7945795/367456) - it shows how you can turn certain requests into 404s in apache. This works as well via the rewrite module by using the `R` (Redirect) flag.

Comment: Problem with that is it's apache based solution and I know very little about it which is why I want very little in my .htaccess file :)

Comment: If you want to get minimal, turn off the computer. That works best, always. And there is not much to do for. ;)

Comment: thats too minimal :), I was hoping to get same/similar solution to wordpress implementation of url rewrite...