# How to hide a specific file in Code igniter / PHP?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a web project and i have created an external photo library for my project.The photo library is outside the web root directory e.g My Codeigniter project is in C:\wamp\www\myprject\application\ but my photo library is under C:\wamp\www\myprject\Lib\

My .htaccess file (under my application folder ) successfully displays the library using the commands below:

**.htaccess** file

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|Lib|css|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]
```

But the problem is this .htaccess file is also displaying my error_log file along with all the images in the library directory.
What changes i will need to make in this .htacess file to hide it?I just want to display (.jpg,gif,.bmp,.jpeg) files.Please help.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do workarounds with 'FilesMatch' tag.

Add this after your RewriteCond and RewriteRule:

```
<FilesMatch "Lib\.(htaccess|htpasswd|ini|log|error_log|error|sh|inc|bak)$">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Note: please add your error log file's extenstion in between the pipe ' | ' symbols. Also please remove extensions that you don't want.

More info:  [How to hide certain file type using apache .htaccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860019/how-to-hide-certain-file-type-using-apache-htaccess)

Comment: Hi @Bilal Khalid please let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an .htaccess guru, but you should be able to change it to:

```
## NOT TESTED ##
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|Lib\/*\.jpg|Lib\/*\.gif|Lib\/*\.bmp|Lib\/*\.jpeg|css|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]
```

`Lib\/*\.jpg` is a regex for any jpg file under the `Lib` directory

Comment: @swatkins.Thanks but it didnt work.It didnt even show my directory contents.