# Sensitive URLs accessible

Tags: php

When I hit url on my browser with .htaccess I can see the code of htaccess. It should be Access forbidden! or not accessible. How can I give restriction to htaccess as no one can access it.

> domainname/.htaccess it's shown me code of htaccess.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

# Send request via index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

php_value memory_limit 256M 
  
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gf58.png)

Comment: Is this a question?

Comment: Yes. i am facing this error. URLs are accessible .

Comment: Give an example of a url that is accessible that should not be?

Comment: What is your question? are you getting any error?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gf58.png   plz see image..

Comment: It's blurry image can't see anything.

Comment: when browser type exp- www.abcexample.com/.htaccess  and enter the show htaccess code.. how to fixed ?

Comment: @DilipHirapara got a my point

Answer (score 0):

Htaccess RedirectMatch can be used to hide/protect certain file extensions:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RedirectMatch 403 \.(htaccess|htpasswd|ini|log|sh|inc|bak|bkp|sql)$

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

result:

```
example.com/.htaccess -> 403
example.com/test -> 200 index.php
example.com/test.php -> 200 index.php
```

Read about at the following question: [How to hide certain file type using apache .htaccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860019/how-to-hide-certain-file-type-using-apache-htaccess)

Answer (score 0):

check your apache.config file.

```
<Files ".ht*">
Require all denied
</Files>
```

Add this code. It will restrict accessing .htaccess file